# NSInvalid Exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[HomeViewController 
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3944710`

I am getting the above exception when i tried to add a tableView in objective C(I can see this in Console) and debugger is getting terminated,please help me to solve this error.

```
 @interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<CacheDBDelegate>
{   
IBOutlet UITableView *tvMainMenu;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tvMainMenu;
```

- (void) setRequiredData;
   }

and

```
    @synthesize arrMainMenu;
    @synthesize tvMainMenu;

   - (void) setRequiredData
   {
    NSMutableArray *menuItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *row=nil;

    row = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
           @"ATM Inquiry", @"ATMINQ",nil];
    [menuItems addObject:row];  


    [self.tvMainMenu selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]             animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];



    if(row!=nil)
    {
        [row release];
    }
    [menuItems release];

   }
```

Comment: Can you show us the call and the method declaration?

Comment: I have edited the above post and added the code snippet.please help to solve this issue.

Comment: But where to you call this method: `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`?

Answer (score 0):

This Error Occurs 
If you are not Properly set the DataSource for the Tableview. Check the DataSource for the Tableview..

Answer (score 0):

You have to missed to implement the required *UITableViewDelegate* and *UITableViewDataSource* methods in your *HomeViewController*.

Here all the *UITableViewDelegate* methods are optional and *UITableViewDataSource* has two required methods **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:**, **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** which you must implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `UITableView` data source and delegate in order to show your data.

```
[self.tvMainMenu selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]             animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

This method is an instance method of tableView and An `UITableView` have which needs table View Data source method.

`UITableView` having some required data source method you need to implement these methods.
check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

also check this for some tutorials on [tableView](http://www.iPhoneSDKArticles.com/category/uitableview)